# mp3 songs trimmed to longer than specified using pydub python library?

Tags: python, pydub

how do i fix this mistake? Here is my code:

```
    from pydub import AudioSegment
    album_path = "/path/album.mp3"
    sound = AudioSegment.from_file(album_path)
    # 203000 milliseconds = 3 minutes, 23 seconds
    song = sound[:203000]
    song.export("/path/song.mp3", format="mp3")
```

however when i open the song that gets saved its 9 minutes and 1 second long when it should be 3 minutes and 23 seconds long and its not silence either, its repeats of the same 3 minutes and 23seconds of the first song of this album. whats going on?

Comment: how long is the original file

Comment: do you have the same issue if you export as wav?

Comment: @Jiaaro exporting to wav solved the problem, thanks! still not sure why mp3 did that though, would be helpful if mp3 worked considering album art cannot be included in wav files

Comment: @megan ffmpeg has a bug where mp3 files are sometiens encoded with incorrect length metadata - as far as I know, the audio data is not duplicated by this bug, but maybe the audio player was set up to loop?